# 'method=PUT' in query parameters

Tags: http, http-headers, articulate-storyline

This is something I have never seen before and I do not know if my Google search skills are lacking, but I cannot find anything saying it is and actual way of specifying the HTTP verb for a request.

To give some context on where I have encountered this: I am working on a project to create a very basic LRS to capture Statements from an Articulate Story.

I had Fiddler running to monitor the requests and noticed the Articulate Story tries to POST to a specified endpoint like so: 'endpoint/statements?method=PUT'

Anybody know what is up with this?

Comment: POST is POST, no matter what a query parameter says.

Comment: That how I know it as well. That is why this was really odd for me. Documentation of Articulate says it 'updates' statements and if you really strict about REST you use PUT. Very weird

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reading of the xAPI specification and the Articulate Documentation, this is something Articulate does... See this link [Implementation of the Tin Can API for articulate content][1]

[1]:https://articulate.com/de-DE/support/article/Implementing-Tin-Can-API-to-Support-Articulate-Content https://articulate.com/de-DE/support/article/Implementing-Tin-Can-API-to-Support-Articulate-Content